# how to search for a sequence in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings and I would like to check if the same consecutive sequence is inside another list of strings.

I want to find this sequence:

```
['dissi', 'io', 'o', 'musa']
```

Within this list:

```
[['sostanza', 'di', 'cieli', 'ed', 'astri', 'cercai', 'per', 'oceani', 'e', 'mari.', 'di', 'donarmi', 'il', 'diluvio', 'ti', 'dissi', 'io,', 'o', 'musa,', 'scorgendo', 'il', 'destino.'], 
['o', 'zeus', 'che', 'infiniti', 'addurre', 'volle,', 'principiando', 'con', 'stormi', 'arditi', 'fulmini', 'di', 'ira', 'molto', 'funesta', 'laddove', 'si', 'alzasse', 'eccessivamente', 'il', 'volare', 'negato', "all'uomo."], 
['', 'imperterrita', 'irrefrenabile', 'poiché', 'memore', 'di', 'ciò,', 'da', 'qualunque', 'principio,', 'ad', 'ogni', 'costo,', 'dea', 'figlia', 'di', 'zeus,', 'narrane', 'cagione', 'e', 'spirito.', '']]
```

The output should be something like this:

```
['dissi', 'io,', 'o', 'musa,']
```

Then the punctuation from the big list should appear in the output.
How could I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the sequence is not found?

Comment: @user56700 i am trying with while and for loops but keep going in loop, i'm stuck on that

Comment: @DarkKnight print an empty list

Comment: Can you firstly show the code you're having problems with and secondly explain the algorithm employed to overcome the punctuation that it seems you want to ignore

Answer (score 1):

This is what I could think of for a quick solution. NOTE: This gives an output even if the words are in different sub-lists

```
ref = ['dissi', 'io', 'o', 'musa']
mainls = [['sostanza', 'di', 'cieli', 'ed', 'astri', 'cercai', 'per', 'oceani', 'e', 'mari.', 'di', 'donarmi', 'il', 'diluvio', 'ti', 'dissi', 'io,', 'o', 'musa,', 'scorgendo', 'il', 'destino.'],
['o', 'zeus', 'che', 'infiniti', 'addurre', 'volle,', 'principiando', 'con', 'stormi', 'arditi', 'fulmini', 'di', 'ira', 'molto', 'funesta', 'laddove', 'si', 'alzasse', 'eccessivamente', 'il', 'volare', 'negato', "all'uomo."],
['', 'imperterrita', 'irrefrenabile', 'poiché', 'memore', 'di', 'ciò,', 'da', 'qualunque', 'principio,', 'ad', 'ogni', 'costo,', 'dea', 'figlia', 'di', 'zeus,', 'narrane', 'cagione', 'e', 'spirito.', '']]


def find_index(word, search_ls):
    if word in search_ls:
        return search_ls.index(word)


clean_mainls = []

for sub_ls in mainls:
    temp_ls = []
    for word in sub_ls:
        temp_ls.append(word.strip(','))
    clean_mainls.append(temp_ls)
    del temp_ls

output_list = []

for sub_list in clean_mainls:
    for wrd in ref:
        idx = find_index(wrd, sub_list)
        if idx is not None:
            ls_idx = clean_mainls.index(sub_list)
            output_list.append(mainls[ls_idx][idx])

print(output_list)

# Output: ['dissi', 'io,', 'o', 'musa,', 'o']
```

Comment: To fix the output from different sub-lists being included, you can use `==` operator by modifying the code to compare the `ref` list and `output_list` list before the loop moves on to the next sub-list iteration.

Comment: Another thing to note is you need to strip the punctuations to clean the list for accurate comparison. Using `re` module might get complicated because the words are so similar.

Comment: thanks, it works very well for what I needed. the only thing is that it gives me problems if I look for consecutive subsequences like ['di', 'ciò', 'da', 'qualunque', 'principio', 'ad', 'ogni', 'costo', 'dea', 'figlia', 'di', 'zeus']

Comment: The code is working fine even if I use the list you gave. Just replace the contents of the `ref` list.